# In tensorflow.js, what is recommended way of reshaping a tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I currently am working on getting a keras trained model working on a browser via tensorflow.js.  I have to reduce the size of the image to 48x48 before passing into my model since all the data I trained on was that size. I've gone about reducing the size of my webcam snapshot to 48x48 using:

```
let imgclone = tf.image.resizeBilinear(imgmod, [48,48], true).toFloat();
```

This allows me to draw correctly to the canvas and get my realtime reduced-size webcam stream in a smaller canvas. I then went to pass the snapshot to my model and I am getting the below error:

> expected conv2d_1_input to have shape [null,48,48,1] but got array
>   with shape [1,48,48,3].

So I just wasn't sure on the proper way of getting my final shaped tensor would be when using tensorflow.js.  I did try to use **tf.reshape(preprocedimg, [null, 48, 48, 1])** but ofcourse this only modified the shape and provided an error that my size didnt match.

Going to continue scouring Google, but thought I would post here as well.  Any info you might be able to provide would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Apparently you are trying to feed a color image into a placeholder which expects a grayscale image? An image with shape [48,48,3] is an image with three channels, i.e. it is an rgb image. An image with shape [48,48,1] is an image with one channel, i.e. a grayscale image. If this is indeed what you want to do, then you can try tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale.

Comment: Thanks tomkot.  However this is Tensorflow.js....it doesn't seem to have any of those utility functions that I can see and I believe I am still going to need the first element as a null. In python this would be pretty simple, I'm just not fully aware of Tensorflow.js' method for achieving this.  I am sure I can hack something together, but was just curious if there was a cleaner way of doing this without slicing and joining. Tensorflow.js API: https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.14.1/#tf.Tensor.expandDims

Comment: You have this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53368649/tensorflow-js-resize-3d-tensor/53381081#53381081

Comment: You cannot reshape. You can only slice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to get a tensor of shape 48, 48, 1, you can use tf.slice

```
  tensor.slice([0,0,0], [48, 48,1])
```

Comment: You're welcome ! Until next question ... Don't forget to upvote the question :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I just want to share the solution I found.

tf.browser.fromPixels (pixels, numChannels?) 
numChannels default is 3(RGB), change it to 1 like below.

```
let tensor = tf.fromPixels(image,1)
```

I hope that helps to you as well.

TensorFlow document (https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#browser.fromPixels)